# Split a Integer every 3rd position and make operations with those numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, split, integer, sum

For example.
I have the Integer=45859694, and I need to split it on this way from left to right
458,596,94 and mupltiply the first number by 7, the second number by 3 and the third number by 1

Comment: Sounds like a homework.. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I need to generate a bank reference and they just give the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String value =Integer.toString();
String tempVal;
int index = 0;
while (index<value.size()){
    if (index+3>value.size(){
       tempVal = value.substring(index);
       //do my operation on Integer.parseInt(tempVal)
       break;
    }
    tempVal = value.substring(index,index+3);
    //do my operation on Integer.parseInt(tempVal)
    index +=3;
}
```

or String.valueof if it isnt an Integer object

Comment: haha got an acceptance and i didnt even type it right, well edited it to fit real answer

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the string representation of the integer (`String.valueOf`), then convert to an array and process the groups of three elements in the array. 
And you're home!